# Kendo Grid Column validation for whole number

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid where i need the user to enter only whole numbers between 0 to 100 to Proposed Discount Column(only editable column in the grid). Even if the user enters the correct value,it shows the error message.

```
fields: {
   ProposedDiscount: {
       validation: {
           required: true,
           proposeddiscountvalidation: function (input) {
               if ((input.val() >= 0 && input.val() < 101) && input.is("[name='ProposedDiscount']")) {
                   input.attr("data-proposeddiscountvalidation-msg", "Proposed Discount should be whole number");

                   return false;
               }  return true;

           }
       }
   }
```

The error i am getting on the ui.

[image]

I am new to Kendo UI.

Comment: Not really 100% sure why, i just followed the example on kendo's web. works fine try this one https://dojo.telerik.com/EZIbuKim -> try edit and type >100 on units in stock. Probably the 'return false should be return (condition)'

Comment: Can you please help me with this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52640067/2504291; @himawan_r